# Not able to insert data to Hbase table using MapReduce

Tags: java, for-loop, mapreduce, hbase

I have written a map reduce job to read data from a file and insert it into Hbase table. But the problem I am facing is that only 1 record gets inserted in Hbase table. I am not sure whether this is the last record or any random record since my input file is around 10Gb. The logic I have written, I am sure that the records should be inserted in thousands in the table. I am sharing only the reducer code and Driver class code as I am pretty sure, the problem lies here.Please find the code below:

```
public static class Reduce extends TableReducer<Text,Text,ImmutableBytesWritable> {


        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            Set<Text> uniques = new HashSet<Text>();
            String vis=key.toString();
            String[] arr=vis.split(":");

            Put put=null;
            for (Text val : values){
                if (uniques.add(val)) {
                put = new Put(arr[0].getBytes());
                put.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("column"),Bytes.toBytes(val.toString()));

                }
                context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(arr[0].getBytes()), put); 
            }

        }
    }
```

My Driver class:

```
        Configuration conf =  HBaseConfiguration.create();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Blank");
        job.setJarByClass(Class_name.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setSortComparatorClass(CompositeKeyComprator.class);

        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.setCaching(500);       
        scan.setCacheBlocks(false); 


        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
                "Table_name",
                Reduce.class,
                job);           

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

After running the program in the console, it says that Reduce output records=73579, but in the table only 1 record is inserted.

```
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201506181703_0020
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 28
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=147158
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=6941462
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=73579
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=7614308352
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=140543
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=417
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=6794286
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=6941462
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=892702720
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=1
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=73579
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=73579
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=10970
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=829947904
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=204120920
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=204121337
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=14198205
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=6941450
15/06/19 16:32:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters
```

And when I write the reducer output to a file, I get the correct output.But not in the Hbase table.
Do let me know what I am missing here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting data into HBase using same Row Key under same Column family and Column Qualifier. And as per your counter statistics, you have only 1 reducer group. So, all your data is getting overwritten in the same cell. That's why you are getting only one row in HBase table.

Comment: Change here put = new Put(arr[0].getBytes()); and modify arr[i], to take dynamic and not 0 always

Comment: It totally depends upon your design. There are two possible ways:
1) Append increment index (i++) to the row key, so that each value in reducer will go to new row key.
2) Append increment index (i++) to the column qualifier name, so that each value will be stored in with different qualifier name under same row key.
Choice totally depends upon your requirements.